# Android PreferenceScreen - Can I use it without saving preferences to SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to use the Android `PreferenceScreen` as a convenient way to layout my user settings, but I don't want to save the preferences to the device shared preferences.  Is this possible, or should I be using a different mechanism such as `ListView`?

It seems really convenient to use the `PreferenceScreen` type because I require different widgets (ie. switches, edit text).  But I'm already running into problems with persistence, ie. anything I enter is persisted even across sessions when I don't want it to be.

settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Preference
        android:key="settings_type"
        android:title="@string/label_type" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="settings_edit_name"
        android:title="@string/label_name"
        android:dialogTitle="Enter a name"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="settings_edit_state"
        android:title="@string/label_state"
        android:summary="Enable or disable the state" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a linear layout and place the non-preference versions of the components you want in it.

Comment: I'm trying to take advantage of the PreferenceScreen because it's a list that allows me to use different widgets within it.  In my example, I don't want any preferences saved.

Comment: Right that is the whole point of the preference widgets, you really just need regular widgets like `EditText` and `Switch`, every preference widget has a regular version too. Just place these in what ever layout you want and then add the listeners you need for them.

Comment: I agree, it's not a good idea to try to override the preference behaviour.

Comment: What is the non-preference versions of the components? For example, what should I use instead for EditTextPreference? I tried EditText, but it can not set summary and display pop-up dialog when I click on it.

Comment: @cges30901 Had they used ids instead of keys, all of this could be avoided, Google being Google. You'll need to do it all manually, but it's easy. Put two `TextView`s vertically inside a `LinearLayout`, one is the title, the other the summary. Then, set an `OnClickListener` on the layout that opens an `AlertDialog`/`DialogFragment` (depending on what you want) with the title, `EditText` and accept/cancel buttons. Style everything as you wish, or you could create custom views that simulate preference widgets.

Comment: @cges30901 if you open any preference widget xml layout, you'll see it's internally a bunch of layouts with normal widgets (textview, imageview, etc). You could in fact just copy it.

Comment: @cges30901 There are no alternatives to preference components

Answer (score 21):

I know that's an old question but I find it quite interesting. Just set this attribute to your preference and it won't be saved:

```
android:persistent="false"
```

Comment: The preference listeners don't seem to get any notification at all when this is set.

Comment: Wonderful, this is the key to separate the view from the logic! Together with `Preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener()` it allows for alternative storage locations and can be used with MVVM like systems.

Answer (score 6):

I re-read the appropriate [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) and determined how to prevent saving preferences by implementing the `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` interface.

> public static interface Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener
>
> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the value of
>   this Preference has been changed by the user and is about to be set
>   and/or persisted. This gives the client a chance to prevent setting
>   and/or persisting the value.

Example:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    public static SettingsFragment newInstance(int index) {
        SettingsFragment f = new SettingsFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.settings);

        // getArguments().getInt("index");

        EditTextPreference namePreference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("settings_edit_name");
        namePreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new NamePreferenceChangeListener());

    }

    private class NamePreferenceChangeListener implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // Do something else presumably and then return false to avoid saving the pref.
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: When returning false from that method, it seems like the state (of for example an `CheckBoxPreference`) doesn't change at all, making it quite hard to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since the preferences are bound to be stored, you can always clear them in onCreate

Try this in onCreate of PreferenceFragment

```
super.onCreate();
getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("custom");
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.apply();
```

Comment: If you save the preferences just to erase them later, I feel that draksia's solution is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a subclass of `PreferenceDataStore` and assigning it to your `PreferenceManager`.

### Preference Data Store

> A data store interface to be implemented and provided to the Preference framework. This can be used to replace the default android.content.SharedPreferences, if needed.
>
> - https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/preference/PreferenceDataStore

### PreferenceManager

> `public void setPreferenceDataStore (PreferenceDataStore dataStore)`
>
> Sets a PreferenceDataStore to be used by all preferences associated with this manager that don't have a custom PreferenceDataStore assigned via `Preference.setPreferenceDataStore(PreferenceDataStore)`. Also if the data store is set, the child preferences won't use SharedPreferences as long as they are assigned to this manager.
>
> - https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceManager#setPreferenceDataStore(androidx.preference.PreferenceDataStore)

### Example

#### CustomDataStore

```
    class CustomDataStore: PreferenceDataStore() {
    override fun putBoolean(key: String?, value: Boolean) {
        when (key) {
            knownKey -> // Do something
            anotherKnownKey -> // Do somthing else
        }
    }

    override fun putString(key: String?, value: String?) {
        when (key) {
            knownKey -> // Do something
            anotherKnownKey -> // Do something else
        }
    }

    // You can ignore unused types but make sure to still override to avoid UnsupportedOperationException
    override fun putFloat(key: String?, value: Float) {}
    override fun putInt(key: String?, value: Int) {}
    override fun putLong(key: String?, value: Long) {}
    override fun putStringSet(key: String?, values: MutableSet<String>?) {}

    override fun getBoolean(key: String?, defValue: Boolean): Boolean {
        return when (key) {
            knownKey -> // Do something
            anotherKnownKey -> // Do something else
            else -> defValue
        }
    }

    override fun getString(key: String?, defValue: String?): String? {
        return when (key) {
            knownKey -> // Do something
            anotherKnownKey -> // Do something else
            else -> defValue
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Be careful while subclassing, because all the abstract `put()` methods will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

#### PreferenceFragment or PreferenceFragmentCompat

```
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    // Prevent saving to SharedPreferences, use a custom data store
    preferenceManager.preferenceDataStore = CustomDataStore()
}
```